# Increment last piece of a version number in bash and store in variable

Tags: bash, shell

Easy question, but i spent too much time to resolve it.

```
1 #!/bin/bash  
2 currentVersion="1.2.0"  
3 someVar=`$currentVersion | awk -F. '{$NF = $NF + 1;} 1' | sed 's/ /./g')`  
4 echo $currentVersion | awk -F. '{$NF = $NF + 1;} 1' | sed 's/ /./g')
```

1, 2 and 4 lines works well. 4 line print 1.2.1 as needed.
I need to set this expression into `someVar` but nothing helped. Please tell how to do it in bash?

Comment: there is an extra `)` on line 3 and 4 (syntax error). on line 3 you should `echo $currentVersion` in order to pipe it to `awk`.

Comment: If you use `$( )` instead of backticks the exact same syntax works inside as would work outside. (Backticks change the meaning of both backslashes and other backticks within them, so you lose that guarantee).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using parameter expansion :

```
someVar="${currentVersion%.*}.$((${currentVersion##*.}+1))"
```

Comment: Arguably the best answer here since it works no matter how many pieces the version number has.

Answer (score 1):

Increment version number with `bash`:

```
currentVersion="1.2.0"
IFS='.' read a b c <<< "$currentVersion"
someVar=$a.$b.$(($c+1))
```

Comment: nit: might want to use useful variable names.  `IFS=. read maj min patch <<< ...` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

The following might work for you?

```
$ currentVersion=1.2.0
$ newVersion=$(echo "$currentVersion" | awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS="." } { $NF=$NF+1 }; 1')
$ echo "$newVersion"
1.2.1
```